# Will chip/crack still be visible after professional repair?

Tags: repair, windshield, cracking

I had several chips on my windshield, one “bullseye” divot and multiple little starburst-shaped cracks. All were caused by roadway stones hitting the windshield while driving.  All were between dime and [quarter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_(United_States_coin)) size.

After being professionally repaired, they are invisible when outside the vehicle gazing at the windscreen. But inside the vehicle, sitting in the driver seat and looking out through the windshield, I can still see sunlight glinting off edges of some of the starburst cracks. The light is muted and off-color compared to before repair, so I know they were not simply missed by the repairperson.

➥ Is it normal for some of the cracks to still be visible after repair? Or should I check back with the repair shop?

Comment: Only sure way to remove all optical defects is to replace the screen - anything else tends to be a temporary repair based on my experience...

Comment: I agree. Repairs can make the screen legal, but they don't make it pretty.

Comment: All repair does is stop the damage from expanding further into the glass.